# What is MobileAccessoryUpdater and why it runs on my MacBook?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

My MacBook Pro 2011 with latest  High Sierra 10.13.02 is suffering from a hard disk usage from time to time. In attempt to track down where all these disk I/O 's are coming from I came across to a "fud" process being called:

/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAccessoryUpdater.framework/Support/fud

What has to do with Mac OS X and can I disable it ?

Comment: [screenshot](https://ibb.co/juTaFR)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `fud` is the firmware update daemon of `com.apple.MobileAccessoryUpdater` that presumably is responsible for firmware downloads for bluetooth peripherals and running the firmware update daemon
(hint for `fud` found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/335524))

To unload/disable it run in a terminal (this will persist through restarts, but probably not OS updates):

```bash
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.MobileAccessoryUpdater.plist
```

To enable/load it again run in a terminal:

```bash
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.MobileAccessoryUpdater.plist
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged" error when doing this. For this you have to boot into recovery mode (boot with Cmd + R) and execute `csrutil disable` first. Thanks.