# macOS doesn't sleep when password is required 15 minutes after screensaver starts

Tags: password, sleep-wake, screensaver, pmset

I run macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013). Except when specified, all settings and behaviours described in this post refer to the Mac connected to a power adapter.

---

My Mac is configured to sleep after 20 minutes of inactivity. The display is configured to sleep after 8 minutes, and the screensaver is configured to start after 2 minutes.

The mac is also configured to require a password 15 minutes after sleep or screen saver begins. For clarity, this setting:

`System Preferences > Security and Privacy > General`

[image]

However, the Mac doesn't sleep when that setting (screenshot) is set to 15 minutes. It also does not ask me to enter the password.

What happens:

1. I stop interacting with the Mac.
2. After 2 minutes the screen saver starts.
3. Time passes: I've tested this waiting for several hours.
4. The mac never sleeps, and the display never sleeps either. The screensaver simply keeps playing.
5. I interact with the mac: move my finger on the touchpad, press a key.
6. The screensaver gets interrupted and I'm back to my desktop. I am **not** asked to enter my password.

It works fine with smaller time values: `immediately`, `5 second`, `1 minute` and `5 minutes`. With those values, the mac goes to sleep as expected (the display sleeps, I assume the mac sleeps as well), and when woken it's locked and it asks me to enter my password as expected.

I haven't tested it yet with larger values (`1 hour`, `4 hours`, `8 hours`), but I'll update the question when I have.

This are my `pmset -g` values when connected to the charger:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelaylow      4200
 standby              1
 womp                 0
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 standbydelayhigh     4200
 sleep                20
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         8
 highstandbythreshold 50
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

I've also discovered that on battery power nothing works. The screen saver doesn't even start. The battery power `pmset -g` values:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelaylow      4200
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 gpuswitch            2
 powernap             0
 disksleep            10
 standbydelayhigh     4200
 sleep                10
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         2
 highstandbythreshold 50
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Comment: My english is too bad to make a really good joke about Fear, Doubt and Uncertainty, therefore the real explanantion: [What is MobileAccessoryUpdater and why it runs on my MacBook?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309329/what-is-mobileaccessoryupdater-and-why-it-runs-on-my-macbook)

Comment: Thanks, but the question is not really about the `fud`. Actually, that comment in parenthesis disappeared when I ran the command again. I'll update the question to remove it.

Comment: Answers to subordinate questions in parenthesis > comment ;-). I know that neither my comment nor the linked q&a answers your question.